# Tooltip not showing up in a chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I define the tooltip:

```
var tooltip = d3.select(TARGET_ELEMENT).append("div")
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.style("opacity", 50)
.attr("style", "position: absolute; pointer-events: none; background: lightsteelblue; width:200px; height:28px;");
```

and then work with it as I have seen in various examples:

```
 g.selectAll("dot")
        .data(Dataset)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yS(d.value[a]); })
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            tooltip.transition()
                 .duration(200)
                 .style("opacity", .9);
            tooltip.html(d["date"] + "<br/> (" +"TEST"+ ")")
                 .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
                 .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            tooltip.transition()
                 .duration(500)
                 .style("opacity", 0);
        });
```

However, nothing is showing up. No errors in the console. I verified that the "mouseover" is invoked correctly but that is it. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: is there any html that is necessary to replicate this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using d3 v4/v5. Just change the tooltip to:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("#target").select(".tooltip").data([0]);
tooltip = tooltip.enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .merge(tooltip)
    .style("opacity", 50)
    .attr("style", "position: absolute; pointer-events: none; background:lightsteelblue; width:200px;height:28px;")
```

You can learn about d3 general update patter [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3808218).

I've also created a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4we6btL1/3/) for this.